# Why I could not save the contents of a file after reading it twice?

Tags: java

Already fixed. Thanks for Mas & ruhul for observing my bugs.

I was trying to read a text file twice, named stationary.txt. The contents of the file has three columns such as the amount, the name of product and the total price.

What I am trying to do first is by averaging each product's price by reading line by line. Then I closed the Buffered and then open it again and read. The second reading takes a variable average and compares each product's price line by line. If line 1 is over the average, then write it into dearer.txt, otherwise write it into cheap.txt

Here is the stationary.txt

```
1 Highlighter 5.99
2 Pen 9.00
3 Eraser 5.00
4 DrawingPin 2.75
5 Highlighter 10.99
6 FountainPen 20.50
7 Pencil 14.50
```

Below is the source code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Ques {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        double average = 0;

        File inFile = new File("stationary.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inFile);
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        File outFilel = new File("dearer.txt");
        FileOutputStream outFileStreaml = new FileOutputStream(outFilel);
        PrintWriter outStream1 = new PrintWriter(outFileStreaml);

        File outFile2 = new File("cheap.txt");
        FileOutputStream outFileStream2 = new FileOutputStream(outFile2);
        PrintWriter outStream2 = new PrintWriter(outFileStream2);

        computeAverage(bufReader, outStream1, outStream2, average);
    }

    public static void computeAverage(BufferedReader bufReader, PrintWriter outStream1, PrintWriter outStream2, double average) {

        String line = "";
        double mark = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            bufReader.readLine();
             while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String [] data = line.split(" ");
                mark = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);

                sum += mark;
                count++;
                    }

            average = sum / count;
            compareMark(outStream1, outStream2, average);   

        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (bufReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufReader.close();
                } catch ( IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    public static void compareMark(PrintWriter outStream1, PrintWriter outStream2, double average) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File inFile = new File("stationary.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inFile);
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String line = " ";
        double sum = 0;
        double mark = 0;
        int count = 0;

        try {
            double ave = (double) Math.round(average * 100) / 100;
            System.out.println("another " + ave);

            bufReader.readLine();
            while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                String [] data = line.split(" ");
                mark = Double.parseDouble(data[2]); 

                if (mark > ave) {
                        System.out.println("Over");
                        outStream1.write(line);
                } else {
                        System.out.println("Less");
                        outStream2.write(line);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } finally {
            if (bufReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        }
    }   
}
```

The source code is perfectly working, just that I received 0 bytes of both files after executing reading twice (first, doing average and last, doing comparison). Why is that? what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: what do you mean by 'after executing reading twice"?

Comment: @AliNasserzadeh I am doing reading twice. First, open the file and average its contents, then close it. Second, open again a file: a variable named average will be compared with each line of the file, the WRITE it in either specified files. Therefore, after executing reading twice is what I am literally doing here.

Comment: u can read file first and store it to collection or anything else then itrate over that twice

Comment: Because you never close your files.

Comment: (output) files need to be closed (at least `flush()`ed) - actually the code is very confusing, inconsistent - partially  opening files in one *level* (method), *eventually* closing on another; I prefer having responsibility (functionality) clearly assigned to a given method, e.g., the one that opens should also close the file (using `try-with-resource` would help that)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I already modified it. Thank you for your criticism in my code readability. I included two functions in my main function, one of which will be average = computeAverage(bufReader, average). then average will be used to computed in computeMark(outStream1, outStream2, average). In other words, when reading first file, I closed it. Then open it again and close.

Comment: another point: reading a file 2 times is not (always) the best solution (depending on what must be done). Consider using a class to represent each line of `stationary.txt` and read that data into a `List<Stationary>` only once. Also check [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) much easier IMO

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger thank you. If you don't mind me asking, you could provide me an example to implement List<Stationary>. I have already fixed this thread's problem. But it is no harm to change/modify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not correct and does not compile. But the main flaws are the following:

1. Your Double.parseDouble(data[2]) shouldn't work with your 4th line of data. Better use Double.parseDouble(data[data.length - 1])
2. Remove the readLine()-calls in front of the while-loop.
3. Write the lines including a line separator.
4. Close the OutStreams

Comment: write the lines with a line separator? I need to edit this line outStream1.write(line);?

Comment: outStream1.write(line + System.lineSeparator());

Comment: thank you so much. The best answer. I already fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

The Data File that you have provided have the columns seperated by a space. As the 2nd Column has data which contains spaces, the convertion of data[2] to double will trigger an exception. Which will make the program to close the buffers and exit.

**Use Commas to seperate column data.**

Use better exception handling to find exceptions easily.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to close those output stream. As you are using bufferredWriter and not flushing it after each write you need to close those output-stream. which will write back those lines or datas into the file. Here is an example how you can do it:
Example 1: using flush().

```
....
   outStream1.write(line);
   outStream1.flush();
} else {
   System.out.println("Less");
   outStream2.write(line);
   outStream2.flush();
}
```

**Example 2: most efficient (either way you need to close those buffer too like bufReader.close())**

```
    ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {

        // add try catch. 
        outStream2.close();
        outStream1.close();
        if (bufReader != null ... ) {
            try {
                bufReader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. and help I already modified.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, an example using `List`

First a class to hold the stationary data, must be completed:

```
public class Stationary {

    private final int id;    // or String if desired
    private final String name;
    private final double mark;  // BigDecimal would be better for money

    public Stationary(int id, String name, double mark) {
        // TODO error checking
        this.id = id;
        ...
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    ... // TODO other getters

    // TODO equals, hashCode, toString
}
```

and to read the file:

```
public List<Stationary> read(File file) {
    List<Stationary> list= new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // TODO parse line into id, name, mark
            list.add(new Stationary(id, name, mark);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

now the list can be used as needed, e.g. average:

```
List<Stationary> stationaries = read(STATIONARY_FILE);
...
for (Stationary stationary : stationaries) {
    sum += stationary.getMark();
    count += 1;
}
...
```

<sub>streams not used to keep it *simple*</sub>